# how to make quote of the day using php and mysql in order by id

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to connect MySQL database and getting out datas
I need it to get only (Data) in order by ID(daily)
and separate both datas and calling them by two different variables
the database looks something like this:

```
------------------------------
| ID |   Data  |  Data2
------------------------------
| 1  |  tea    |   hot
| 2  |  milk   |   hot
| 3  | pepsi   |  cold
```

and output will be only one line (one data)

I don't make it as above :) it's just for clarifying....and what's best collation and type for huge data in UTF-8 ?

**Edit:**
Can you make it return 5 rows instead of 1? by ID? for e.g. for first day (1-2-3-4-5)ID's and for second day (6-7-8-9-10) and so on?

Comment: What is your question? You can use `TEXT` for your column type and the `utf8_unicode_ci` collation. What else do you want to know?

Comment: I am so bad on asking a question sorry..I save a lots of data(7000-10000 lines)that's why I've chosen MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    quotes
    ----------------------------------
    | id | data        | data2
    ----------------------------------
    | 1  | first quote | translated quote
    | 2  | second...   | bla bla
```

And then you select it like:

```
   $firstday="2011-06-06";
    $getquote = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE id=(DATEDIFF(CURDATE()+1, '$firstday'))");
$quote = mysql_fetch_object($getquote);
echo $quote->data . $quote->data2;
```

**EDIT!!: I have eliminated datediff, so the ID returned from date difference is DIRECTLY in WHERE.**

What this does is **calculate difference between first day and current date**. So each day that datediff will be 1 bigger. 
`DATEDIFF(CURDATE()+1, '$firstday') as datediff` can be interpreted as

```
datediff = differenceBetween(Currentday +1 and firstDay)
```

- Yesterday was 2011-07-06, therefore `datediff = 2011-07-07 (there is +1!) - 2011-07-06` which is **1**
- today, it's `2011-07-08 - 2011-07-06` which is **2**
- tomorrow `2011-07-09 - 2011-07-06` which is **3**
- day after tomorrow `2011-07-10 - 2011-07-06` which is **4**
- in one month it will be `2011-08-08 - 2011-07-06` which is **33**

so, **datediff is each day bigger by 1**

```
quotes
-------------------------
|id| data
-------------------------
|1| quote          day 1 (because date difference from start == 1)
|2| quote 2        day 2 (datediff == 2)
|3| quote 3        day 3 (datediff == 3)
|4| quote 4        day 4
.....
```

### Or shortly: Each day will be a different quote, starting with ID 1 forward.

I can't explain more then this..

---

**EDIT #2: 5 quotes a day**

```
$offset = date_diff(new DateTime('now'), new DateTime('2011-08-29'))->format('%d');
$getquote = "SELECT * FROM quotes LIMIT {$offset},5";
```

second edit thanks to ajreal ([SQL LIMIT syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262372/sql-limit-syntax-error))

---

**EDIT #3: 5 quotes a day, changeable by variable..**

option 1:

```
$choose=0; //statically defined, only first of that day will pop out
```

option 2:

```
$choose = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["qid"]); //which one will be defined in url.. (watch out, people can figure it out and browse through all quotes
```

option 3:

```
$choose = rand(0,4); //will choose it randomly from those 5 daily quotes
```

So pick one of those options you like, and add it before this:

```
$offset = 5*date_diff(new DateTime('now'), new DateTime('2011-08-29'))->format('%d') + $choose;
$getquote = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE id = '$offset'");
$quote = mysql_fetch_object($getquote);
echo $quote->data . $quote->data2;
```

Comment: Hi, it's me again :( There was a few errors...I fixed some problems but there's another error: 'mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource' I've echoed it and here's the source of the error:'Query failed: Unknown column 'datediff' in 'where clause' Actual query:'

Comment: @Omer edited, i hope it works. I had to get a bit help on this one

Comment: thank you so much Bojan K. but can I separate each of the quotes?

Comment: @Omer, how would you like to separate them? Each of them on their own page (with id in url) or in a list one after another? If you know any php&mysql you can do that yourself..

Comment: by php variable if possible. point me the to the right direction

Comment: I see. but can you explain a little bit more, what I mean is how I can separate each of them. sorry but I don't have enough skill to do that. :(

Comment: @Omer (forgot 5*, added) Alright, with the #3 edit, you have 5 quotes each day. You have `$offset`, which is `date_difference*5 + $choose`. That `$choose` is to move through them, 0 is the first one, 4 is the last one. If it's more than 4 you will access next days quote. You can set that `$choose` from `$_GET` or some other way, you can also generate `$choose` randomly

Comment: I'm still can't get this to work I tried a lot.can you write an example of one id? does the mysql_fetch_object remain as before?? because every time it return errors

Comment: mysql_fetch_object(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Comment: @Omer, i forgot mysql_query... fixed

Comment: if you show me an example with the $choose that would be great. but what will happen to echo $quote->data . $quote->data2; ?

Comment: @Omer i really really hope this works coz I'm sort of sick of it :D

Comment: I feel that way too, sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a fixed quote through all the day just have the first client of the day do a RAND() on the table and choose a random quote.

**Then mark that quote as the quote for the current day and serve it for all other users.**

Repeat.

Comment: but I need it in order by id not random!

Comment: @Omer sorry but the way you asked your question... makes it hard to understand what you're aiming for. You want to feed the user a quote for the day, correct? Assuming you'll have more than 30 quotes... you'll have to select them randomly or sequentially. If you want to select the quotes in a sequential fashion just have the first client of the day move the quote to the new one.

Comment: My aim is for a daily sayings and and translated sayings(data and Data2) and to show it one by one(daily) I am showing both of sayings and translated sayings. but in order(by table ID)
sorry for my bad questioning