# How to use User-Defined Variables in the limit statement?

Tags: mysql, pagination, limit

I want a paging query in common format, not hard code, by this:

```
set @pageSize = 10; set @pageIndex = 2;

select * from city LIMIT (@pageIndex-1)*@pageSize, @pageSize;
```

but the mysql told me that:

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '(@pageIndex-1)*@pageSize, @pageSize' at line 1

what's the problem about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL LIMIT syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262372/sql-limit-syntax-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the user defined variables with LIMIT.

> MySQL Doc says *"User variables may be used in most contexts where
>   expressions are permitted. This does not currently include contexts
>   that explicitly require a literal value, such as in the LIMIT clause
>   of a SELECT statement, or the IGNORE N LINES clause of a LOAD DATA
>   statement"*

But you can achieve similar functionality using *'user defined function'* or *'[stored procedure](http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2010/11/22/how-to-use-user-defined-variable-in-mysql-limit-clause/)'* or 'plain SQL by calculating @rowid and using it in the where clause'.